# select - populate when editing post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have my angularjs view in wich I must populate my select box with value saved in database, and to allow for other options to be selected. I have tryed like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label" for="status">Status zaposlenika</label>
 <div class="controls">
 <select required name="status" class="form-control" ng-model="employee.status"  ng-options="statusType.name for statusType in statusTypes" >
</select>
</div>
```

But my value is not populated in my view. ( {{employee.status}} - > "test" )

```
$scope.statusTypes = [

     {
        name: 'test'
     },

    {
        name:'Test1'
    },

    {

        name: 'Test2'
    },

    {

        name:'Test3'
    }
];
```

How can I do this ?

**EDIT**

My model employee.status is populated with value "test". But my select box is not. Othe values are listed as items for selection. How can I set default value that is saved in my database to be pre-selected in my select box.

Comment: You don't have value `test` in you `statusTypes`, so it can't be selected.

Comment: model employee.status is populated with data that is fetched from db using service and $resorce

Comment: Oh sorry, value is there my bad. But that is not working.

Comment: So model value is the string like "Test1"?

Comment: Yes it is a String - "test"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model `employee.name` is a string and selectbox is bound to an object similar to `{name: "Test1"}`. So if you want to select option from `statusTypes` you have to find corresponding object in array of object.

```
$scope.statusTypes = [
    {name: 'Test1'},
    {name: 'Test2'}, 
    {name: 'Test3'}
];

var selectedStatus = $scope.statusTypes.filter(function(type) {
    return type.name = 'Test2';
})[0];

$scope.employee = {
    status: selectedStatus
};
```

So you have to make `employee.status` to be one of the objects from `statusTypes` array.

Or other option is to continue to use string for `employee.status` and change `ngOptions` to bind to a string instead of object:

```
ng-options="statusType.name as statusType.name for statusType in statusTypes"
```

Comment: One very strange thing happen's, when i upadate my values, sometimes it works sometime it wont work :( Sometime value is bound to that string sometimes it is not. I am using secound option.

Comment: I'm afraid "sometimes it wont work" is really hard to debug.. Maybe  you can replicate the issue somehow in plunkr? Otherwise it's hard to find a problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is hard to replicate problem. I get my data from MongoDB with Node.js as back-end. Using AnlugarJS factory and $resource. Strange thing is that my employee model is populated in wright way (all data is there when I "print" {{employee}} in my view.) But sometimes my select box is not showing data that is in employee.status  ..Wierd

Comment: I get this strange extra option when it is not working : <option value="? string:Test ?"></option>. Related question is [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value[/link]

Comment: It happens when you use ng-options="statusType.name as statusType.name.. ?

Comment: Yes, I have solved it by "manualy" adding options. e.g. <option>Test</option>. Now it works fine. I am sorry for my bad language skills. I am intrested why is that happening.

Comment: I'm also very interested why this ?strange ? option appears. Maybe I will try to find the answer in source code.