# AngularJS ng-model not setting correct value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a table and when clicking on a row I call this function:

```
 $scope.updateRow = function(row) {
     $scope.row = angular.copy(row);
}
```

**$scope.row** has a name attribute and I have a select menu that should display this name:

```
<select name="rowName" ng-model="row.name" required required-message="'A name must be selected '" class="sa-select">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option ng-repeat="name in names" value="{{name.fullName}}">{{name.fullName}}</option>
</select>
```

However when clicking the row it sets the option value in the select menu to

```
<option value="? string:test name ?"></option>
```

even though **$scope.row.name** = "test name"

The option value should look like:

```
<option value="test name">test name</option>
```

Seems to be a similar issue to this question: [Angular adds strange options into select element when setting model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value)

Comment: Do you have any plunkr ?

Comment: It looks like you're using name.fullName for the value when name is a string "test name"?

Comment: What is `row` object is it the same objects that are in `names` array?

Comment: the row object has a name attribute and several other attributes, this select menu only shows the names

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="rowName" ng-options="name.fullName as name.fullName for name in names" ng-model="row.name" required required-message="'A name must be selected '" class="sa-select">
```

Not tested tho, but you can read more here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

And if you would want to add a default option it would look like this:

```
<select name="rowName" ng-options="name.fullName as name.fullName for name in names" ng-model="row.name" required required-message="'A name must be selected '" class="sa-select">
<option value="your value"> your text </option>
</select>
```

Comment: yea I tried ng-options and it doesn't work unfortunately