# Angular injects "string:" before value in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a `ng-options` list defined with a HTML select element such as:

```
<select
    required="required"
    ng-model="vm.selectedOption"
    ng-options="item.name as item.label for item in vm.options">

    <option value="">Select an option</option>
</select>
```

This however results in the following HTML:

```
<option value="string:VALUE" label="Option Name">Option Name</option>
```

I am using Angular version 1.4.8, does anyone have a solution how to solve the `string:` issue or at least can explain to me why this is occurring?

The `vm.options` array looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "INFILL_AUTOMATIC",
    "label": "Automatic"
  },
  {
    "name": "INFILL_GRID",
    "label": "Grid"
  }
]
```

//EDIT:

When logging `vm.selectedOption` I just see the correct value. So the `ng-model` does in fact have the correct value. But why is Angular giving the default `value` then this prefix, is it using this prefix to define the "type" for the `ng-model` or something?

Comment: Try to output `vm.selectedOption` into the view, I suspect that nothing is wrong with what you see

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular adds strange options into select element when setting model value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value)

Comment: @mic4ael I saw that post as well but the suggestion there was to use `ng-options`, which I am already using instead of `ng-repeat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This behavior is documented in the angular changelogs, as a breaking change for Angular 1.4-beta.0.  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-17

Basically, in order to preserve duplicate checking within `ng-options`, if a list of primitive values are supplied to `ng-options`, the value's type is prepended to the value in order to create a unique hash key to track (this differs from earlier versions of angular, which would track by the index or the key of the item in the collection).

In practice, this should not affect most usages of `ng-options`.  If it is important for you to preserve the `value` parameter of the dropdown, you can use the `track by` parameter in `ng-options` in order to provide an alternate key to be used for duplicate tracking.

Note that this differs from `ng-repeat`, in that `ng-repeat` cannot generate a surrogate key using this method, since it would affect the behavior of the repeated elements. Therefore if a duplicated list is passed to `ng-repeat` without a `track by` clause, `ng-repeat` will produce an error and not render the items, where `ng-options` is able to render the list.

Comment: Thanks @claies that explains it!

Comment: Using "track by" causes the drop down to lose default value auto select. like if you ng-model="modelId" and model already has a value, it's not select by default. How do you fix that?

Comment: @TatiOverflow default values definitely should work;  you might want to open a new question with a [mcve] showing how it isn’t working, and reference this question if you believe it is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jGOX2nCJfexddiOC9lGR?p=preview)

And JS:

```
    <select ng-model="template"    ng-options="c as (c.label + ' - ' + c.name) for c in options">
```