# Angular adding weird option to md-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I am having a user fill out a contact form which includes a dropdown to select what county they are located in.

I am currently using `ng-repeat` to create 50+ options.

HTML:

```
<md-select name="county" ng-model="form.county">
    <md-option ng-repeat="county in counties" value="{{county.abbrev}}">{{county.abbrev}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

JS:

```
.controller('slothController', function($scope) {
    $scope.counties = ('Not in California,Alameda,Alpine,Amador,Butte,Calaveras,Colusa,Contra Costa,Del Norte,El Dorado,Fresno,Glenn,Humboldt,Imperial,Inyo,Kern,Kings,Lake,Lassen,Los Angeles,Madera,Marin,Mariposa,Mendocino,Merced,Modoc,Mono,Monterey,Napa,Nevada,Orange,Placer,Plumas,Riverside,Sacramento,San Benito,San Bernardino,San Diego,San Francisco,San Joaquin,San Luis Obispo,San Mateo,Santa Barbara,Santa Clara,Santa Cruz,Shasta,Sierra,Siskiyou,Solano,Sonoma,Stanislaus,Sutter,Tehama,Trinity,Tulare,Tuolumne,Ventura,Yolo,Yuba').split(',').map(function(county) {
    return {abbrev: county};
})
```

This works perfectly on the users side, but once the user submits the form (I am also serializing it to JSON), and let's say they selected `Santa Clara` as their county.

I would receive an email that has `? string:Santa Clara ?` as the form value for the county.

I want to get `Santa Clara` without the `? string: ?` in my email.

I was looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value) thread earlier, but I couldn't find a good solution to my problem because `ng-options` does not work with `md-select`.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me solve this problem, I have spend the past 8 hours trying to solve it.

Comment: do you mean `county` instead of `country`?

Comment: directly loop through json....and attack key as well as val to country.abbrev on fly...that's what the syntax does

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Error: [ngRepeat:iidexp] '_item_' in '_item_ in _collection_' should be an identifier or '(_key_, _value_)' expression, but got 'country as county.abbrev for country'.`

Comment: @CaetanoMelone It should be `county` not `country`...

Comment: @Clint, thanks. But I am still getting the same error as above.

Comment: @Caetano Melone Problem must be in where you are serializing it to JSON. Otherwise I have tested, it is working fine.

Comment: @Rakeschand, are you using angular material? For some reason I am still getting the same error as above

Comment: yep i'm using angular material

Comment: Can you take a look at this pen? http://codepen.io/cmelone/pen/LNaerb @Rakeschand

Comment: I didn't suggested that. your commented code is working..

Comment: I'm still getting `? string:County ?` in the response. what do you use to serialize it to json?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using jQuery, why not just use angular? There might be some weird things going on with indexing (as mentioned) because you're using ng-repeat for options then use jQuery to get the result.

Comment: I actually need jQuery anyways, and I got it to work by just removing the extra characters.

Comment: What you are doing with the string splitting  is very hacky and possibly not working in all browsers or future versions of angular/jquery.

Comment: What do you think could solve the issue I am having? Now I really don't want to use jQuery since it just brought up a bug in my web page. @kuhnroyal

Comment: Something like this maybe, adjust the email. http://codepen.io/kuhnroyal/pen/pyYXNw

Comment: It works ok at first, but when I try to submit, I am getting these errors in my console. `POST https://formspree.io/caetanomelone@gmail.com 400 (BAD REQUEST)` and `Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"error":"Can't send an empty form"},"status":400,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"url":"https://formspree.io/caetanomelone@gmail.com","data":"Alpine","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"BAD REQUEST"}`