# Setting the initial value of AngularJs Selector

Tags: angularjs

When ever i am trying to set the inital value in the angularJS selector, it returns a *"blank"* element with the value `"<option value="? number:1000139 ?">`

how can i achieve setting the default value, without having it set to some gibberish.

my selector looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="dataToCheckForImport.importContractId" ng-init="dataToCheckForImport.importContractId=opt.selectedContract">
   <option ng-selected="{{option.contract.kontraktID == dataToCheckForImport.importContractId}}" value="{{option.contract.kontraktID}}" ng-repeat="option in opt.allContracts">{{option.contract.kontraktID}} </option>
   <option value="-1">In Column</option>
 </select>
```

and this is the output iam getting: 
[image]

ive tried setting it as a string aswell, this only made my output have a "string format" like `"<option value="? string:1000139 ?">`

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Add opt.allContracts data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone finding this, the problem is when types do not match each other. 
in my example i tried to initialize my selector with a string and not a number as every other option is a number.
Making all value "strings" solved my problem. 
also covered in this question: 
[Angular adds strange options into select element when setting model value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783294/angular-adds-strange-options-into-select-element-when-setting-model-value)